# Умножение двух списков с вложенными списками

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

Есть два списка

```
а = [[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8]]
```

и

```
b = [[[1],[1,2],[2],[1,2]],[[1],[],[1,2,3],[1,2,3,4]]]
```

Необходимо умножить два списка, получив результат в таком виде

```
[[[1],[2,4],[6],[4,8]],[[5],[6],[7,14,21],[8,16,24,32]]]
```

Comment: Ничего не понятно. Объясните словами, как должно происходить сложение.

Comment: а они всегда такой структуры? и во втором списке именно [] или [1] ?

Comment: Бывают пустые. По количеству элементов в первом списке, всегда кратное количество подсписков во втором. Количество элементов в подсписках второго переменное.

Answer (score 3):

Я так понимаю, речь идёт от адамаровом произведении матриц?
Не совсем понятно, как у вас работает умножение на пустой список.
Пока могу предложить такое решение:

```
import numpy as np
a = [[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8]] 
b = [[[1],[1,2],[2],[1,2]],[[1],[],[1,2,3],[1,2,3,4]]]

a = np.array(a)
b = np.array([np.array(x) for y in b for x in y])
b = b.reshape(a.shape)
res = [x.tolist() for y in np.multiply(a, b) for x in y]
print(res)
```

Получим `res`:

```
[[1], [2, 4], [6], [4, 8], [5], [], [7, 14, 21], [8, 16, 24, 32]]
​
```